# Sample Togglz implemetation with spring boot kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, togglz

Can anyone help me with sample example for spring-boot-kotlion with togglz feature.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [the official Togglz documentation for Kotlin](https://github.com/togglz/togglz/blob/d77ce995e589dc47a280ecbff7ef7061c6092e2b/kotlin/README.md)? It has the example you're looking for.